# How to get RecordID from CNContactStore ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cncontact, cncontactstore

This is my code to get the device's Contacts and save to `MutableArray`.

But I need to get the `recordID` for all contacts individually and save into the same Array for further use. (For example, to delete Contacts using `recordId`).

Please help me, I'm stuck for 4 days on that.

```
[contactStore enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:nil usingBlock:^(CNContact* __nonnull contact, BOOL* __nonnull stop){
           if( contact.phoneNumbers)
                phoneNumber = [[[contact.phoneNumbers firstObject] value]];
           if( contact.emailAddresses)
                emailAddress = [[contact.emailAddresses firstObject] value];
           contactValue=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];               
                [contactValue setValue:phoneNumber ?:@"" forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
                [contactValue setValue:emailAddress ?:@"" forKey:@"emailAddress"];
                [contactValue setObject:contact.identifier forKey:@"phoneIdentifier"];
                [contactValue setObject:contact.givenName ?:@"" forKey:@"firstName"];
                [contactValue setObject:contact.familyName ?:@"" forKey:@"lastName"];

           [_totalContact addObject:contactValue];
      }]
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What are you not able to do? And what do you mean by "save into same array for further use"?

Comment: i want to delete selected contacts. Do you know how to delete selected contacts?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below. I have verified this code myself and it works perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question statement what I understand is that you want to `delete` a *contact* from the contact book based on the `identifier` of that *contact*. When you have the `identifier` then this is all you need to do:

```
- (void)deleteContactWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {

    NSArray *keys = @[CNContactGivenNameKey,
                      CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
                      CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
                      CNContactIdentifierKey];
    CNMutableContact *contact = [[store unifiedContactWithIdentifier:identifier keysToFetch:keys error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSError *error;
    CNSaveRequest *saveRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
    [saveRequest deleteContact:contact];
    [store executeSaveRequest:saveRequest error:&error];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adeel  its work perfect. 
Can you how to merge duplicate contacts ?

Comment: Sure @InderpalSingh. I would suggest that you ask a new question for that as it'll go off topic on this post. You may add the link of the new question here in a comment.

Comment: here is the link @Adeel [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613589/how-to-merger-the-duplicate-device-contacts-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple extension, if you really need to read `recordID` (for old API).

`recordID` always fetched.

***This code never submit into App Store. It use a private API!***

`CNContact+PrivateExtension.h` :

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface CNContact (PrivateExtension)

@property (readonly) NSNumber *privateRecordID;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

`CNContact+PrivateExtension.m` :

```
@implementation CNContact (PrivateExtension)

- (NSNumber *)privateRecordID
{
    return [self valueForKey:@"recordID"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you used this on iOS 11 beta?, using valueForKey:@"recordID" on the CNContact object on iOS 11 crashes and gives the message "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key recordID." as if Apple drop the support for ABAddressBook properties